# There is no possibility to sort a date column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, datepicker

I added a date column with the `DatePicker` to my `DataGrid` and there is no possibility to sort this column by clicking the `Header`.

I suppose it is related with my date formatting, but I can't find solution to this.

My code is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate">
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd\-MM\-yyyy}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditingDateTemplate">
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="trainingsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,42,12,12">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" Header="Data" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingDateTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the [SortMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).